# Why does the COO- ion is pulled at during critical Micelle concentration?

Tags: physical-chemistry

During the Micelle formation of a soap (made of sodium), when soap comes in contact with water, it dissociate into Na+ ions and RCOO-  ions(where R is an hydrocarbon chain). Then in the RCOO- ions, R is  hydrophobic and COO is hydrophylic. So at critical Micelle concentration, what happens to this RCOO- ion?

Comment: "R is hydrophilic and COO is hydrophobic" -- You sure?

Comment: I am sorry. It is the opposite. R is hydrophobic and COO is hydrophylic.

Comment: Nothing happens to the **single** ion. The ion still remains pretty much the same, with hydrophylic head and hydrophobic tail, and the forces acting upon it are also the same. Consider a simpler analogy: you put $\ce{NaCl}$ in water, it dissociates into certain ions, you add more and more of it, everything goes well, until at about 360g/L... something happens.